# Display encrypted image on UIIImageView in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, uiimageview, aes

I encrypted an image (png) by using AES (Encryption algorithm) and get encrypted NSData. I use [FBEncryptor](https://github.com/dev5tec/FBEncryptor) framework. Now I am trying to display it on UIImageView, but it does't work. Here is my code:

```
@interface ImageEncryptingViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *encoptdImg;


@end

@implementation ImageEncryptingViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);

    NSData* encryptedData = [FBEncryptorAES encryptData:imageData key:imageData iv:imageData];

    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:encryptedData];

    NSLog(@"%@", encryptedData);

    _encoptdImg.image = image;



}
```

In the end I want to get encrypted image, where we can see noise or something else, but not original image. For example this [website](http://www167.lunapic.com/editor/?action=encrypt) do it. I need it on ios by using AES encryption algorithm. How I can solve this problem? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You can't display it because you encrypted it. What are you trying to accomplish with encryption?

Comment: Decrypt the encryptedData use following method..    + (NSData*)decryptData:(NSData*)data key:(NSData*)key iv:(NSData*)iv

Comment: @zaph I am trying get encrypted image. I mean the image where we can see only noise or something else, but not original image.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in *this question* is that you encrypt the whole image file instead of the bitmap solely. The file contains meta information that is needed to display the image. I. e. the file has [a signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Technical_details) at its beginning to mark it as PNG. Encrypting the file, you destroy that signature.

You have to encrypt solely the bitmap.

This leads to the next question, how to get the pure bitmap data out of an image. Fortunately this question is answered on stack overflow several times, i. e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics).

Answer (score 0):

lunapic.com is using a [placeholder image](http://www167.lunapic.com/do-not-link-here-use-hosting-instead/148719842324541?8731775755)
you can just put such image as a placeholder for an encrypted image, an encrypted image will not have any image attributes in order to get `UIImageView` to read it, when user decrypt the image, then you can just place the decrypted image in that placeholder, that's it